# Goto URL on clicking Link in CAutoComplete [Yii]

Tags: yii, jquery-autocomplete

I am using CAutoComplete in Yii application.

I am trying to return links based on search query. I am able to return that also.

Now if I will click that link whole link is copied to the search bar. Is it possible to goto url on clicking the link?

Code :

Controller -

```
$products = Product::model()->findAll();
foreach($products as $product) {
    $return[] = CHtml::link($product->name,array('product/view','id'=>$product->id));
}
echo implode("\n",$return);
```

View -

```
$this->widget('CAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'search',
    'value'=>CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->request->getParam('search')),
    'url'=>array('ajax/suggestProducts'),
    'multiple'=>false,
    'selectFirst'=>false,
    'htmlOptions'=>array('placeholder'=>Yii::t('main','Search Products'),'id'=>'searchbar')
));
```

Comment: Yeap its possible... But, we need your codes. Paste them pls...

Comment: ok. sorry... its time to goto home... i am going to answer this question 2 hours later. Sorry again...

Comment: Hey man, you got any solution?